# Character limit then new line?

Tags: c++, string, printing, output, concatenation

Im trying to create a table that's 32x32.

I have a very long bit stream that comes in as a string.

I want to print out this string but it prints it as one long line. After 32 characters are printed, I want to start a new line. Is this possible in C++ with functions?

```
    if (counter = 32) {
    cout << bitStream << "\n"; //bitStream being the string that is length n
    counter = 0;
    }
    else {
    cout << bitStream; 
    }
```

Comment: Yes it is possible.  What have you tried?

Comment: Updated the original with the code that I tried. Not sure if you can even do something like that. Im new to C++ so I have no idea.

Comment: What is `bitStream`?

Comment: Use the *remainder* operator: `if ((counter % 32) == 31) cout << "\n";`.

Comment: I tried using mod but it still won't output anything.

Comment: Loop over the characters of the string. In each iteration, output a character and use the if statement shown above to go to the next line.